# XSLT - Identify consecutive nodes which has same patterns of attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have xml like this,

```
<section>
        <p id="ss_main">aa</p>
        <p id="ss_chap">bb</p>
        <p id="main">cc</p>
        <p id="main">dd</p>
        <p id="main">ee</p>
        <p id="ss_main">ff</p>
        <p id="main">gg</p>
        <p id="main">hh</p>
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
        <p id="ss_chap">xx</p>
        <p id="ss_main">yy</p>
        <p id="ss_chap">zz</p>
    </section>
```

what my requirement is place new nodes named `<ss_start>` and `<ss_end>` by covering existing nodes witch are start with `ss`.

so the output should be,

```
<section>
        <ss_start/>
        <p id="ss_main">aa</p>
        <p id="ss_chap">bb</p>
        <ss_end/>
        <p id="main">cc</p>
        <p id="main">dd</p>
        <p id="main">ee</p>
        <ss_start/>
        <p id="ss_main">ff</p>
        <ss_end/>
        <p id="main">gg</p>
        <p id="main">hh</p>
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
        <ss_start/>
        <p id="ss_chap">xx</p>
        <p id="ss_main">yy</p>
        <p id="ss_chap">zz</p>
        <ss_end/>
    </section>
```

I can write xsl like follows to cover specific node by `<ss_start>` and `<ss_end>`

```
<xsl:template match="p[@id='ss_main']">
        <ss_start/>
        <p id="ss_main"><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
        <ss_end/>
    </xsl:template>
```

but I'm struggling to find consecutive nodes that id attr starting from `ss` and cover them by `<ss_start>` and `<ss_end>`.

Can anyone suggest me a method how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## XSLT 1.0 sibling recursion

In XSLT 1.0 you can do this as follows, which uses a technique called *sibling recursion* (though *sibling traversal* is probably a better term).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section/*[starts-with(@id, 'ss')]" priority="5">
        <xsl:if test="self::*[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][starts-with(@id, 'ss')])]">
            <ss_start />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="self::*[not(following-sibling::*[1][starts-with(@id, 'ss')])]">
            <ss_end />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which, when run against your input, will create this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>
   <ss_start/>
   <p id="ss_main">aa</p>
   <p id="ss_chap">bb</p>
   <ss_end/>
   <p id="main">cc</p>
   <p id="main">dd</p>
   <p id="main">ee</p>
   <ss_start/>
   <p id="ss_main">ff</p>
   <ss_end/>
   <p id="main">gg</p>
   <p id="main">hh</p>
   <p id="main">ii</p>
   <p id="main">jj</p>
   <ss_start/>
   <p id="ss_chap">xx</p>
   <p id="ss_main">yy</p>
   <p id="ss_chap">zz</p>
   <ss_end/>
</section>
```

I see now that you tagged your question with xslt-2.0, which means you can use grouping. I'll try to update with an example in XSLT 2.0.

## XSLT 2.0 group-adjacent

In XSLT 2.0, you can use a boolean true/false as the the group-adjacent grouping key as follows, which is quite a bit shorter than the XSLT 1.0 code above:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="starts-with(@id, 'ss')">
                <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key()"><ss_start /></xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
                <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key()"><ss_end /></xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[starts-with(@id, 'ss')]
                      [not(starts-with(preceding-sibling::p[1]/@id, 'ss'))]">
  <ss_start />
  <xsl:next-match />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[starts-with(@id, 'ss')]
                      [not(starts-with(following-sibling::p[1]/@id, 'ss'))]">
  <xsl:next-match />
  <ss_end/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```