# c#: how to know if the two element are in a row using xml linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have this simple xml

```
<parent>
    <child>
      <son attribute="1"/>
      <sp>
      <son attribute="2"/>
      <sp>
    </child>
    <child>
      <another child>
        <son attribute ="3"/>
        <sp>
      </another child>
    </child>
    <child>
      <son attribute="5"/>
    </child>
</parent>
```

here is my code for now. actually i dont know what's next

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(string);
foreach (var el in doc.Descendants("child").ToList())
{
}
```

so the output will be

```
<parent>
        <child>
          <son attribute="1"/>
          <sp value="1">
          <son attribute="2"/>
          <sp value="2">
        </child>
        <child>
          <another child>
            <son attribute ="3"/>
            <sp value="3">
          </another child>
        </child>
        <child>
          <son attribute="5"/>
        </child>
    </parent>
```

my problem is how do i check if the `son` and `sp` tag are next to each other, if its next to each other, the `sp` tag will get the attribute value of the `son` tag

Comment: You may be better off trying to use XSLT for this job instead of straight C#. I haven't used XSLT in a while, but C# definitely supports it and these SO questions may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274312/how-to-match-and-wrap-identical-and-adjacent-node-together-in-xslt-1-0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701706/xslt-identify-consecutive-nodes-which-has-same-patters-of-attribute-values

Comment: What if it sp is not next to son?

Comment: @DarkKnight nothing happens, like in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it..

```
var xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var getReadyForSp = false;
string sonvalue = "-1";

foreach (var ele1 in xmldoc.Element("parent").Elements("child"))
foreach (var element in ele1.Elements())
{
    if (element.Name == "son")
    {
        getReadyForSp = true;
        sonvalue = element.Attribute("attribute").Value;
    }
    if (getReadyForSp && element.Name == "sp")
    {
        XAttribute attribute = new XAttribute("value", sonvalue);
        element.Add(attribute);
        getReadyForSp = false;
    }

}
```

But you need to make sure sp element has valid format, which is `<sp/>`

Comment: it working, but how about for the son and sp tag that are inside another tag? i updated the example sir, thank you

Comment: @imadammy : Do you have predefined set of element names that are part of this nested structure. Logic will get a bit complex if you are unsure how many more `anotherchild' kind of intermediary nodes exist.